# Facebook upload video ad: Error Code : 1363030. "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed"

Tags: php, facebook, curl, video, facebook-php-sdk

I'm getting the following error in when I'm trying to upload video ad:
`Error Code : 1363030`.

> Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again

The connection is fine and the video isn't too big .. chunk (1MB).

Any idea what the problem could be?

My code:

```
$transfer = array();
$transfer["access_token"]      = "G4535PZXXX";
$transfer["upload_phase"]      = "transfer";
$transfer["upload_session_id"] = $upload_session_id";
$transfer["start_offset"]      = $start_offset";
$transfer["video_file_chunk"]  = @$filepath;

print_r($transfer);
//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ($transfer as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/act_XXX/advideos');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$transfer_response = curl_exec($curl_connection);
//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .                   curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

**Edit:**
To create the chunks I used this command

```
shell_exec('split --bytes='. $fb_response["end_offset"] . ' --suffix-length=1 --numeric-suffixes '. $this->filepath .' $chunkfilepath' );
```

Comment: Consider posting some code/what you've tried.

Comment: Where are you uploading the video? I see all of the post variables being set, but no actual content for the binary file to be sent.

Comment: the file already on server .. the $chunkfilepath and $filepath already defined on the start of my code .. its not relevant because its local on my server. i added the command i used for the chunks

Comment: Yes, but where are you uploading the video to facebook? Are you simply trying to link to the video? The video may exist on your server, but nowhere in your code are you sending the file to their server.

Comment: the POST $transfer["video_file_chunk"]  = @$filepath;

Comment: Right, you're only sending the file path, not the contents of the file.

Comment: "The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path." http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Improved formatting and formulation of question

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile.
see CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```html
$video_file_chunk = new CURLFile($filepath,'video/mp4');
$transfer = array();
$transfer["access_token"]      = "G4535PZXXX";
$transfer["upload_phase"]      = "transfer";
$transfer["upload_session_id"] = $upload_session_id";
$transfer["start_offset"]      = $start_offset";
$transfer["video_file_chunk"]  = $video_file_chunk;

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/act_XXX/advideos');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $transfer);

//perform our request
$transfer_response = curl_exec($curl_connection);
//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' .                   curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

For whomever finds this later, this Facebook error occurs if you don't specify the content type and file name of the attached file (i.e. if you pass it as an inline field value, not as an attached file).

I don't use PHP often, so can't really give the correct curl command, but the code above seems to have a bug because it uses `@` operator (“suppress errors”) instead of passing an `@`-prefixed file name to curl. The corresponding line should read:

```
$transfer["video_file_chunk"] = '@' . $filepath;
```

Not sure if this is enough to fix the overall issue in PHP.

Comment: The fix is likely to use `new CurlFile()`.  There's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42366495/114558) about this.